# Python ImportError: No module named Dropbox, when launching from executable

Tags: python-2.7, dropbox-api

My Python 2.7 application is using the dropbox api as remote storage. As well, I'm using the flask framework to create a RESTful API.

The issue I'm having seems to be stemming from running program as an executable, i.e. after doing a

> chmod a+x run.py

and trying to run my application using

> ./run.py

I'm getting the following error:

> ImportError: No module named dropbox

Along with the call stack leading to the module where dropbox is imported. I should note that before creating the executable, I had no issues. Also, I've tried creating a dummy file with the exact same code, and running it from the command line using

> python run.py

and I've had no issues. I could link my code, but I don't think its a coding error to be honest.

Is this a known issue with the dropbox api? I haven't found any documentation to support it, and I'd like to know whats going on to avoid or circumvent in the future. Maybe something is no longer supported, or needs to be upgraded that I'm not aware of?

SOLUTION: 
Thanks to Karl C below for leading me towards the solution. I had installed flask later on in the project, and had previously installed the dropbox api using a different interpreter. The solution was to run

```
flask/bin/pip install dropbox
```

Comment: does your shebang line at the top of `run.py` use the same python interpreter as the one in your path?

Comment: wow great catch. Hit it right on the head. I'm fairly new to python so I didn't even think to check that